# Add attribute to sales->order->Create new order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add new attribute in magento admin panes:

`> sales > order > create new order`

I want to sales persons name which will be fetched from the current user login in admin panel.
Then order type which is drop down and referred by which is also a drop down.

Please tell me how do i move ahead with it?
Which files to edit and so on all the details properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to create your new attribute on the order entity:

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$installer ->addAttribute('order', 'my_attribute', array(
    'label'     => 'My New Attribute',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'position'  => 1,
));
```

Now you will need to modify the admin view to show the new attribute:

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml**

```
<?php if($_order->getMyAttribute()): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Attribute') ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMyAttribute() ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: How do i create the order attribute of drop down type. I need one text attribute and two drop down attribute, Can you help me with this?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module

Answer (score 1):

The new attribute must have a default (non-null) value in order to work. the attribute is not writable if it has a 'NULL' value in the database.  So using this attribute options array  may work for you

```
$attribute  = array(
'type'          => 'int',
'label'         => 'attribute_code',
'default'       => 0,
'visible'       => false,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => true,  
'comparable'    => false );

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'attribute_code', $attribute);
```